# Delete all rows in big query table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that I use for unit tests where I run some code, query the table check that the data was successfully added and then delete the full contents of the table.

How would i go about deleting every single row in the table?

I would rather not have to recreate the table.

efficiency isn't a factor as I'm only dealing with less than 10 rows each unit test.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM `projectid.datasetid.tableid` WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: I would argue with this solution, because every time you run the unit test and run this DML query, you have to pay for 10MB of data( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing). A assume that, because this is a unit test it occurs frequently. The other problem, if more devs are running the unit test, there can be a race condition. shouldn't be a better solution to put a TTL on the dataset and create a new table every time with a randomized table name?

Comment: hmm, ok so this applies to all types of queries ? cause I changed my plan from deleting the added data to just querying the data added in the past 2 seconds. as for efficiency, I'm not going to be running these tests too much so it should be fine, I just want to test that the full pipeline is working

Comment: The only free querying thing on bigquery is metadata and streaming buffer reads as far as I know. But even if you are working with streaming inserts, you have to wait while the streaming buffer contains no data. (DML part: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert) And once it is "manifested", you have to pay for at least 10MB of data.

Comment: you can read the streaming buffer? how would i be able to do that, would probably be best for these tests seeing as its free

Comment: Only works with time partitioned tables. You have the use the `_PARTITIONTIME IS NULL` statement in you query. Still though, querying and deleting the a table in a unit test while others can use this table as well, it's not a good practice imo.

Answer (score 3):

This alternative doesn't charge the 10MB min:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `temp.replaceable`
AS 
SELECT *
FROM `temp.replaceable`
LIMIT 0
```

Comment: this does work, but the schema is not persisted with this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can set write_disposition to `WRITE_TRUNCATE` in order to erase the table before inserting. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/WriteDisposition). In order to use this, you'll have to use a job to insert your data. I could not find a way to make this work with streaming inserts.

Here is an example in python:

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, 'my_dataset')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
with open(filepath, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file,
        table_ref,
        job_config=job_config,
    )  # API request
    job.result() # Waits for table load to complete.
```